# Cucumber run tests on several sites

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs, playwright

I have a list of tests which i need to run on several sites

I can do scenario outline in each test with examples of sites, but if list of sites is changed i need to change a list in each scenario. Background does not have outline function.

```
@test
Scenario Outline: Test for several sites
When I navigate to <site>
Then something
Examples:
|site|
|https://www.test.com|
|https://www.test2.com|
|…|
```

Maybe somebody have ideas how more correctly do it?

Answer (score 1):

Alot depends on how many tests are common and how many tests are specific to each site.

If all the tests are common the best way is to extract the site out of the test and use an environment variable to set the site. Then you would run cucumber with the environment variable e.g. something like

```
cucumber site_tests SITE=http/your.site.com
cucumber site_tests SITE=http/my.site.com
```

For things like user accounts etc. You can be clever and have site specific things in support code in your features, or use more environment  variables.

This will keep you features much simpler and avoid the need to use scenario outlines.

---

If you only have a couple of tests that have to be run on many sites then I would write a feature or perhaps just scenarios for each site e.g.

```
mysite.feature

Background:
  Given site is my site 

Scenario: Login
  Given I am registered
  When I login 
  Then I should see mystic
```

and

```
yoursite.feature

Background:
  Given site is your site

Scenario: Login
  Given I am registered
  When I login 
  Then I should see your site
```

You can still share most of your step def and code if you are clever and write scenarios with a high level of abstraction.

---

There are of course alot of other solutions in between, but in general I would strongly advise against a solution based on scenario outlines.

---

Hope thats useful :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you can assign variables to all these sites and use these variables in the feature files. you can read the value of these variables in step definition during execution from a constants file. that way you can simply update them in a single place.